# The recursive sum

Tags: java

Find out what is wrong in the following recursive sum function:

```
public int sum (int x){
  if(x==0) return 0;
  else return sum(x-1)+x;
}
```

1. The base case should return 1 instead of 0
2. The base case should be `(x<=0)` instead of `(x==0)`
3. etc.

The answer is 2. But I don't see anything wrong with keeping `(x==0) return 0;`, what do you think?

Comment: Define "wrong". What should the function return for negative input?

Comment: Thank you. The method is supposed to sum the values from 1 to `x`. Wrong is given from the instruction manual with no further explanation as what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: the type int of variable x comes inside the parentheses

Comment: I would have removed the else. If the if-condition is true, then it exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question is quite ambiguous, given the answer there's only one way to interpret it:

The only difference in behavior between the original given program and the "fixed" program is when the input is negative. Given the statement, the reasonable result when the input is negative is to return `0` (which is what fixed program does), while the original program loops indefinitely (and causes stack overflow/undefined behavior).